# javax.mail.MessagingException Is throwing when I try to connect via IMAP to Gmail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

*Trying to connect to gmail via IMAP connection, catch* **javax.mail.MessagingException**

```
public static StringBuffer getEmailByBody(String username, String password, String containsMsg) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    try {
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username , password);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Fail in connection" + ex.getMessage());
    }

    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    Message[] messages = null;
    boolean isMailFound = false;
    Message confirmationMAil = null;

    // Search for mail MAX 10 runs
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        messages = folder.search(new BodyTerm(containsMsg), folder.getMessages());
        for(Message message : messages){
            if (!message.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                confirmationMAil = message;
                isMailFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // wait for 3 seconds if message is not found
        if (!isMailFound) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    // Search latests for unread mail
    for(Message message : messages){
        if (!message.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
            confirmationMAil = message;
            isMailFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Test fails if no unread mail was found from God
    if (!isMailFound) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find email");

        // Read the content of mail and launch registration URL
    } else {
        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                confirmationMAil.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

> javax.mail.MessagingException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
>     nested exception is:
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:670)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
>       at insynctive.utils.MailManager.getEmailByBody(MailManager.java:39)
>       at insynctive.utils.MailManager.getVerificationCode(MailManager.java:106)
>       at insynctive.pages.insynctive.TwoFAPage.sendViaPrimaryEmail(TwoFAPage.java:49)
>       at insynctive.tests.PersonFileTest.loginWith2FAEmail(PersonFileTest.java:148)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:659)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
>       at insynctive.runnable.RunnableTest.run(RunnableTest.java:36)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:860)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
>       at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.(Protocol.java:116)
>       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.(IMAPProtocol.java:115)
>       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:685)
>       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:636)
>       ... 29 more
>   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MailManager.getEmailByBody("asd@gmail.com", "password", "Hello");
}
```

Comment: This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) might help.

Comment: More details, please.  What exactly did you try?  What were the results?  Where is your Java program running?  In an application server?  As a standalone program?

Comment: Is a simple algoritm to get emails from GMAIL, 2 days before, it works.

Comment: If it worked before and now it doesn't work, then something changed.  We can't possibly guess what changed; you're going to have to figure that out.  If the suggestions in the FAQ entry didn't help, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Gmail block all external access, I resolved that problem cancelling all the gmail security in the account.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before you call Session class:

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path to your cacerts file in your Java folder, inside your hard disk);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "false");
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", port);
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", port);
        prop.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
        MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add this line of code `prop.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");`

Comment: Could you be more elaborate and explain where to inject this line, and why it would be a solution?